# Go lang Using SQL Boiler with Limit, Offset

Tags: go, slice, limit, offset, sqlboiler

I am using SQL boiler and GOlang

```
"github.com/volatiletech/sqlboiler/v4/queries"
    "github.com/volatiletech/sqlboiler/v4/queries/qm"
```

I want to set limit, offset and orderby in different columns

my code is

```
    queryMods := []qm.QueryMod{
        qm.OrderBy("hive_id"),
        qm.Limit(10),
        qm.Offset(0),
        qm.Load(dbmodels.HiveUserDemographicRels.Answer),
        qm.Load(dbmodels.HiveUserDemographicRels.Question),
        qm.Load(dbmodels.HiveUserDemographicRels.Hive),
    }
    where := fmt.Sprintf(`hive on hive_user_demographic.hive_id=hive.hive_id and hive.deleted_at is null `)
    queryMods = append(queryMods, qm.InnerJoin(where))
    demographic, err := dbmodels.HiveUserDemographics(queryMods...).All(ctx, m.db)
```

using this code the limit and offset are based on the table HiveUserDemographic

But I want to set  limit and offset  in  "Hive" table (dbmodels.HiveUserDemographicRels.Hive)
like the mysql

```
SELECT hive_user_demographic.*
            FROM  (
            SELECT *
            FROM   hive
            where  deleted_at is null
                order by hive_id asc
                LIMIT  10
                OFFSET 0
            ) hive_data
            JOIN   hive_user_demographic  on hive_data.hive_id=hive_user_demographic.hive_id
```

I tried this

```
queryMods := []qm.QueryMod{
        qm.Load(dbmodels.HiveUserDemographicRels.Answer),
        qm.Load(dbmodels.HiveUserDemographicRels.Question),
        qm.Load(dbmodels.HiveUserDemographicRels.Hive, qm.Limit(1), qm.Offset(0)),
    }
```

but not working

it getting panic error

[{Answer []} {Question []} {Hive [{1} {1}]} {hive on hive_user_demographic.hive_id=hive.hive_id and hive.deleted_at is null  []} {hive.hive_id asc} {`hive_user_demographic`}]

&{0x2096ca0 { []} [Answer Question Hive] map[Hive:[{1} {1}]] false map[] [] [] false [`hive_user_demographic`] [{0 hive on hive_user_demographic.hive_id=hive.hive_id and hive.deleted_at is null  []}] [] [] [{hive.hive_id asc []}] [] 0 0   }

hive_user_demographic have hive_id (eg 1,2..) with 10 row in each..
Hive table have hive_id (eg 1,2..) one each row.
so I want to set limit and offset in hive table.

How can I set